I can't access the cookie even though it has been set on browser
i use expessJS, cookiePaser and try access cookie but it always return undefined eventhough it has been set on browser
this is options cors
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.use(cookieParser());

this is fetch
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signin", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        });

this is set cookie
res.cookie("access_token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            sameSite: 'None',
        })

this is access cookie
export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.cookies.access_token;
console.log(token);
if(!token) {
    return next(errorHandler(401, 'Unauthorized!!'));
}
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (error, user) => {
    if(error) return next(errorHandler(401, "Forbidden!!"));
    req.user = user;
})
next();

}
Every time I access the cookie it returns undefined.

httpOnly: true means it won't be accessible from code in the browser - though now I re-read your question, it seems you want to read it on the server ... but you don't show that code

const token = req.cookies.access_token;
console.log(token);
if(!token) {
return next(errorHandler(401, 'Unauthorized!!'));
}
jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (error, user) => {
if(error) return next(errorHandler(401, "Forbidden!!"));
req.user = user;
})
next();
Here is it

put code in the question

SameSite=None also requires secure, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#none; but secure also means, clients are only supposed to send this cookie back when the connection is made via HTTPS ... you're just using HTTP.

Quote MDN: "Note that insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the Secure directive, and therefore can't use SameSite=None."

Hi, Is the issue still persisting ?

If the intention is to access the cookies via Javascript on the frontend specifying a cookie as httpOnly will prevent this. httpOnly is an added layer of security to help prevent cross site scripting attacks.
Express gives you some information in their documentation about the various different properties you can apply to a cookie.
In your case, if you do want to access the cookie via javascript you would have to remove the httpOnly property from res.cookie like so
res.cookie("access_token", token, {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            sameSite: 'None',
        })

To access the cookie on the backend, you need to make sure you're able to parse the cookies. Install a relevant parser to retrieve the cookies. For example,
npm install cookie-parser
Then. You'd want to set the middleware in your express application. And then finally retrieve the cookie in the endpoint :)

const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// cookie-parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/some_endpoint', (req, res) => {
    // Access the access_token cookie
    const access_token = req.cookies.access_token;

    // rest of your logic
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});



You've assumed wrong :p
